# Likely just a dumb mistake, but what's wrong with this create table statement in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
ProductID           INTEGER,
ProdName            VARCHAR(50),
Category            VARCHAR(20),
SupplierID          CHAR(1),
HourlyRate          DECIMAL(5,2),
UnitsInStock            CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT PKProduct PRIMARY KEY ProductID,
CONSTRAINT FKSupplier FOREIGN KEY SupplierID
REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID)
);
```

Keeps giving me this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CONSTRAINT FKSupplier FOREIGN KEY SupplierID REFERENCES
>   Supplier(SupplierID' at line 8

Probably just a simple stupid mistake, but does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: You are missing a comma after `FOREIGN KEY SupplierID` ... voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: primary key and foreign key column must be enclosed with parenthesis. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aba9dc

Answer (score 1):

Because keys can be composite (i.e. include multiple fields) they need to be wrapped in parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
ProductID           INTEGER,
ProdName            VARCHAR(50),
Category            VARCHAR(20),
SupplierID          CHAR(1),
HourlyRate          DECIMAL(5,2),
UnitsInStock            CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT PKProduct PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
CONSTRAINT FKSupplier FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID)
);
```

For Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
ProductID           INTEGER,
ProdName            VARCHAR(50),
Category            VARCHAR(20),
SupplierID          CHAR(1),
HourlyRate          DECIMAL(5,2),
UnitsInStock            CHAR(2)  ,
CONSTRAINT PKProduct PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
    CONSTRAINT FKSupplier FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
    REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID)

);
```